# what is Request header /Content length in chrome devtools for scorm package in LMS?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, scorm1.2, articulate-storyline, lms

actually my LMS provider is saying that scorm package is sending too much data to lms which killing the server. I have made a scorm package in Articulate storyline, and LMS provider is saying that problem in my scorm package but that lesson behaving differently every time for different users. Content length should be  in kb but it's going in Mb. Please anyone tell me is really a problem of content or LMS, because when we uploaded this scorm package to LMS 1 year back, was working fine but now they are saying that now they have identified this problem after getting so many queries regarding LMS slow speed.

PFB, screenshot which they have shared with us.

[https://prnt.sc/1170b4i](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DvcxQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with the LMS as most of them limit the length of questions and/or answers (interactions) to 255. If your Scorm is v1.2 then you should also ensure that there are no Unicode or UTF8 characters in the interactions. Scorm 2004 doesn't have this problem.